# Get together PHP and AJAX in Wordpress to implement YouTube video

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a function that gets the YouTube videos to my WordPress page.

```
function get_official_trailers() {
    global $post;

    $videoID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true);
    $season_number = 1;

    if ($videoID != "") {
        $videoID = explode(",", $videoID);
        foreach ($videoID as $videoID_singular) {
            echo '<div class="videoContainer">';
            echo "<h3 title='off-trailer-title'>" . (get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),
            'show_name', true )) . " Season " . $season_number++ . " Official
            Trailer</h3>";
            echo wp_oembed_get( 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' .
            $videoID_singular );
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }
}
```

This function allows me to get a part of the YouTube video URL like this **5hAXVqrljbs** from WP Custom field, then add it to "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=," separate my videos if there is more than one parameter in the WordPress custom field string, and, finally, display all the trailers at one page.

But the problem is that I need to accomplish this idea through a button click.

I've created the AJAX function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.mybutton').click(function () {
        var post_id = $(this).data('postid');
        var postData = {
            action: 'get_trailers',
            post_id: post_id,
        }

        $.post( ajaxurl, postData ).done(function(result) {
            $('.result_area').wrapInner('<div class="videoContainer"> </div>');
            $('.result_area').html(result);
        });

    });

})
```

Of course, I've added it to WordPress

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_trailers', 'my_fun');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_trailers', 'my_fun');

function my_fun() {
    $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
    $pt = get_post_meta($post_id, 'video_url', true);
    wp_send_json($pt);
    wp_die();
}
```

At the moment, all I managed to achieve is just to get the data from the WP Custom Fields via AJAX. But I can't figure out how to accomplish the entire idea of my initial PHP function.

Thus, my final goals are:

1. I push the button .mybutton (done);
2. I get data from the custom fields (done);
3. Send it as JSON to AJAX (done);
4. I get these data through .mybutton click;
5. Separate my data from dMgElg_aEuI,5hAXVqrljbs to

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hAXVqrljbs

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMgElg_aEuI

I don't know how to do it in jQuery.

6. Show my 2(3,4,5) separated trailers in the div videoContainer. I don't know how to realize wp_oembed_get in jQuery.